# np.any() with condition on list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to use a condition where if any element of the list is less then some value then I should get stop the loop, However the following implementation doesn't work and returns

```
import numpy as np
j=[1,20,100]
if np.any(j < 20):
   break
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: np.any is for numpy arrays, not for lists in general.  `j = np.array([1, 20, 100])` should do what you want.

Comment: And if you don't want to bother with numpy, `if (any x < 20 for x in j)`.

Comment: In Python all function arguments are evaluated **before** being passed to the function.  So `j<20` is run first.  The error telling us that it does not work when `j` is a list.  Passing it to a `numpy` function does not change that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error states, you cannot compare elements of a list to a number by simple `j<20`. However, you can do that with numpy arrays, so you would need to convert your list to a numpy array first using following code:

```
j = np.array([1,20,100])
```

or if you already have a create list:

```
j = np.array(j)
```

Then the rest of your code should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems like you would like to see if any element in j is less than 20.
You can do that with

`if np.any([element < 20 for element in j]):`

(This line uses list comprehension.)